# Bootstrap 3 collapse (only show specific columns)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to web coding entirely and I'm trying to create a grid of art projects for an online portfolio using bootstrap.

I'm trying to make specific columns show on a grid when the relevant button is clicked.

Currently when I click the text 'Video' it hides everything that isn't a video project as desired, but if I then click 'Photo', the video projects will hide and the photo projects will still be hidden and won't show.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <a href=".novideotag" class="btn tagbtn" data-toggle="collapse">Video</a> |
  <a href=".nophototag" class="btn tagbtn" data-toggle="collapse">Photo</a>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid text-center">
    <div class="collapse in col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 novideotag">
      <p>example: photo project 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse in col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 nophototag">
      <p>example: video project 1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to click 'Video' and show only video projects, click 'Photo' and show only photo projects but I'm not sure I'm going about it the right way; perhaps some javascript is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a very basic jQuery solution to implement the show and hide feature. First assign a ID to the link and use the `click()` method of jQuery to initiate the click event. `e.preventDefault()` is used to override the browser's default click behaviour.

To implement the show and hide, call `show(), hide()` or `slideUp(), slideDown()` methods. There are many ways to do this. But this is one of the alternatives.

```js
$('#video').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.novideotag, .design').slideUp();
  $('.nophototag').slideDown();
});

$('#photo').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.nophototag, .design').slideUp();
  $('.novideotag').slideDown();

});

$('#design').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.nophototag, .novideotag').slideUp();
  $('.design').slideDown();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <a href="#novideotag" class="btn tagbtn" data-toggle="collapse" id="video">Video</a> |
  <a href="#nophototag" class="btn tagbtn" data-toggle="collapse" id="photo">Photo</a> |
  <a href="#design" class="btn tagbtn" data-toggle="collapse" id="design">Design</a>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid text-center">
    <div class="collapse in col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 novideotag">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      <p>example: photo project 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse in col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 nophototag">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      <p>example: video project 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse in col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 design">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      <p>example: Design Project</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: While this clearly works when I run code snippet, this does not work at all in my document; it's completely unresponsive unless I add a '.' before 'novideotag' etc. after <a href=".I tried creating a new html document to test it using a new document and it still didn't work (could not find the document /novideotag).

Comment: Not sure about that. I guess relative URLs might be playing a role for unresponsiveness.

Comment: here's an example: http://te-al.co.uk/portfolio.html as you can see, if you click videography, it shows only video but projects, but then click photo and design projects will appear when they shouldn't.

Comment: Well, you need to adjust the code accordingly. Check out my edit.

Comment: Or else use `filter()` http://api.jquery.com/filter/ to find out the specific class.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that the javascript has no effect on what's happening at all, and functions exactly the same whether it's there or not.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time Manoj, I've got it working now by simply adding 'type=text/javacript' to <script> and by placing the script at the bottom of the container-fluid <div>.